# Proving that S/I is a vector space

Tags: ring-theory, vector-spaces, ideals, quotient-spaces

I'm given a polynomial ring $S=K[x_1,...,x_n]$ and $I$ is an ideal of $S$.

I'm working on proving that the quotient ring $S/I$ is a vector spake over $K$. Since S is a ring, we already have some of the vector space properties, such as closure under addition, multiplication and distributivity, etc. I need to show two additional properties for $S/I$ to be a vector space.

The first property is $\forall u,v\in S/I,(u+v)\in S/I$

My attempt at this is by letting $u=a+I$ and $v=b+I$, where $a,b\in S$. Then $u+v=(a+I)+(b+I)$, by the associative property on rings, $u+v=(a+b)+(I+I)$. by closure under addition, $a+b\in S$, but then I need to show that $I+I=I$. Can I say that $I+I=\{x+y|x,y\in I\}$, which is clearly equal to $I$, since $0\in I$, so setting either $x$ or $y$ to $0$,  we can find every element in $I$ inside $I+I$. But isn't $I+I=2I=\{2x|x\in I\}\neq I$.

For the second property: $\forall u\in S/I$ and $c\in K$, $cu\in S/I$

Similarly, I let $u=a+I$ for some $a\in S$. So $cu=c(a+I)=ca+cI$ by the distributive law of fields. $ca\in S$, since $S$ is a ring. But then how do I show that $cI=I$.

Comment: Both $\;S\,,\,\,I\;$ are vector spaces over $\;K\;$ and $\;I\le S\;$ , so you simply have here the quotient vector space. And $\;cI\le I\;$ since this is an ideal and it is thus closed under product by elements of the ring, which contains (an isomorphic copy of) $\;K\;$ .

Comment: $I + I$ is not the same as $2I$.  In the first case you get $x + y$ for any $x$, $y$; in the second case you only get $x + x$ for any $x$.  So $2I$ is smaller in general, and is not relevant to the proof.  You should be able to show that $I + I \subseteq I$ easily by looking carefully at what it means for $I$ to be an ideal.

Comment: As an aside, your question makes it look like like you're actually having trouble with the *ring structure* on $S/I$.

Answer (score 1):

This is the curse of too much information.

**Theorem** If $F$ is a field and $\varphi : F \to R$ is a ring homomorphism, then $R$ is a vector space over $F$ with scalar multiplication $f \cdot r = \varphi(f) r$.

Your problem follows, using the composite $K \to S \to S/I$.

(the converse is true too: if a ring $R$ has the structure of an $F$-vector space that uses the same addition operation, then there is a ring homomorphism $F \to R$ given by $\varphi(f) = f \cdot 1_R$)

Comment: @Bob: My point in stating the theorem is that it's simpler to prove the general theorem than it is to prove the special case, both because you can use previously known facts and because you won't get distracted by irrelevant details. The canonical map $K \to S$ is just $a \mapsto a$, and the canonical map $S \to S/I$ is just $a \mapsto a+I$ (when $S/I$ is realized as the ring of cosets of $I$)

Comment: @Bob: I don't see what use doing so would have at all. BTW, comments here are for clarifying *this* answer. If you have a new question, you should post it as a new question on the site (and link to this one if you want). Note the OP was quite confused when he wrote the OP, so you surely don't have the *same* question the OP did. (and also, that's why I found it so important to emphasize getting rid of the cluttering details that could be contributing to the confusion)

Comment: @Bob: The reader is intended to prove the theorem for themselves.